# Re-designing for Mobile First Design

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have already designed a webpage before learning about mobile-first design.

When creating a responsive design I made 3 classes: .mobile, .tablet, .desktop.

I call to all these classes in my navigation bar, but apparently don't need to call to my mobile query when designing for mobile first (I understand why). Whenever I remove my .mobile class it shows the mobile information, and then when I re-size the window to a larger window the mobile information stays and then the tablet/desktop information is added. How would I go about correctly re-designing this?
This is my main content in working form when resizing windows.

```css
/*Mobile Query*/

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop,
  .tablet {
    display: none;
  }
}


/*Tablet Query*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width:768px) {
  .tablet {
    display: block;
  }
  .mobile,
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}


/*Desktop Query*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .desktop {
    display: block;
  }
  .mobile,
  .tablet {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 class="mobile">About Me</h2>
<p class="mobile">I will not disappoint and I will perform to the best of my ability.</p>

<h2 class="tablet">About Me</h2>
<p class="tablet"> I am somebody who tries their best not to disappoint. I fear that my disappointment will reflect poorly upon myself and people who are close to me. This is something that motivates me to work hard and not to complain. Currently, I work part-time at a
  grocery store, run a side business, and go to school more than full time.</p>
</article>

<h2 class="desktop">Strengths</h2>
<p class="desktop">One of my strengths include being very talented at learning or developing new ways to complete objectives. I always enjoy learning about different perspectives, and I believe it is needed to be successful. Another one of my strengths is the ability to
  see an error and immediately want to correct it rather than ignoring it and leaving somebody else to fix it. I am driven to be the best at anything I do while wanting to help other people and make their jobs easier.</p>
```

Comment: But your three blocks are the same html ... I think you don't get the point of media queries. Or is this just a terrible example ? The point is to change the CSS of the same element at different screen sizes, there are just few case when you need to have specific blocks to show/hide

Comment: Why would you hide all of that content on any viewport size? Seems fairly valuable to the user. You don't have miles of content.

Comment: It isn't ALL the information for the desktop viewport

Comment: I think you misunderstood, even if you have more content for desktop, why are you making these different versions? Seems like there's a lot of valuable information that will be shared at the desktop level and very little of value shared at the mobile level. I would provide the same content at all levels unless I had an **extremely good** reason for not doing so. I'm simply asking, why are you taking this approach? What's the reason behind it?

Comment: Anyways, if you remove `.mobile` from an element it's always going to be visible. So I would expect it to be visible at all screen sizes. As it stands, your code works. The content only appears at the appropriate screen sizes. In the end, your question is unclear and hard to decipher what the goal is.

Comment: I'm taking a class for website designing and it said to only display the most important content. The professor wants me to have the content change based on the viewport, but then said I don't have to use a mobile viewport at all for my mobile-first design. Sorry, I didn't realize it was hiding additional comments or I would've commented sooner.

Comment: I've been dumb, I read that I don't need a mobile query as I don't need a mobile class. I removed my mobile query, and then added Display: none; to the classes .tablet and .desktop.        TYVM for the help and realization

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to answer half of my question so far. In the beginning I had for my Nav bar:

```
<nav>
<div class= "mobile">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">About Me</a></li> 
    <li><a href="projects.html">My Projects</a></li> 
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="education.html">My Education</a></li>
</div>

<div class="tablet">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">About Me</a></li> 
    <li><a href="projects.html">My Projects</a></li> 
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="education.html">My Education</a></li>
</div>

<div class="desktop">
    <ul><a href="index.html">Home</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="portfolio.html">About Me</a></ul> 
    <ul><a href="projects.html">My Projects</a></ul> 
    <ul><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="education.html">My Education</a></ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

and it is now:

```
<nav>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">About Me</a></li> 
    <li><a href="projects.html">My Projects</a></li> 
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="education.html">My Education</a></li>
</nav>
```

Because I changed my .desktop query

```
/*Desktop Query*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .desktop {
        display: block;
    }
    .mobile, .tablet {
        display: none;
    }
    nav li {
        background-color: #FFA500;
        border-radius: 1em;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: .3em;
        padding-right: .3em;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        display: inline;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}
```

My mobile and tablet information were the same in this case, with the only changes coming to this section being visual changes, so I changed my desktop query to include the visual changes instead of using li for one set of changes and ul for another.

For hiding content and displaying content, I kept the classes and removed my mobile query. I still retained the .mobile class. I added display: none to both my tablet/desktop classes so that they will never be displayed, but then with my tablet/desktop query, it has display: block, so it blocks the none display revealing them depending on viewport size.

Example: If my screensize is 500 pixels, it will classify as a desktop viewport, so my query tells my HTML to hide my .mobile and .tablet class, which tablet class is already hidden. It also tells my HTML to block the previos display command to my .desktop class, which was to hide it, so it ends up showing it.
I hope this is even interpretable.